# Cloudpebble "Installation failed. Check your phone for details."

Tags: android, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I'm using [Cloudpebble](http://cloudpebble.net) to develop a watchface for myself. Everything compiles well and I've not had troubles sending the face to my watch until now.

After compiling the watchface and linking to the phone, it returns an error of "Installation failed. Check your phone for details." However, the phone does not shed any light on what these details might be.

I've checked the usual suspects such as full watch slots and inability to connect to phone, but those were not issues in my case and I'm rather stumped as to what the problem might be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Pebble App Version:
    <strike>2.1.0-beta9</strike> 2.1 (Android)
Watch Firmware: <strike>2.7</strike> 2.8
Watchface Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/tinnvec/tinntime)

UPDATE 11/20:
I didn't mention before that the phone app would crash often when attempting to load my watchface on the watch because I chalked it up to beta software. Today brought watch firmware 2.8 and phone app 2.1 proper, and while the phone app no longer crashes, the mysterious error continues without additional information on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my particular issue, as it turns out, was that I had unused fonts. It's not a very obvious problem, so I hope this helps others out.

The main issue really was poor error reporting from cloudpebble due to the lack of error clarification returned from the pebble app to cloudpebble.

I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/pebble/cloudpebble/issues/116) on the [cloudpebble github](https://github.com/pebble/cloudpebble) (that's where I found the answer) so if any further developments happen, they'll more than likely be there.

Comment: @CGTheLegend Sadly there was never information on my phone, through googling and the issue I opened on the cloudpebble github, I was able to narrow down and eventually find the problem

Comment: You might have unused images too - that's what happened to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the app had to be on a specific page for it to properly install on the pebble. I found this to be true if I installed on the terminal using the Pebble commands or using the web IDE [CloudPebble](https://cloudpebble.net/ide/).

The app has to be on the "My Pebble" scene/activity. Make sure when you attempt to install an app to Pebble that you are on that scene/activity regardless if you are installing using the web IDE or the command line.